# Regular expression to extract sub string in groups

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract names from the following input using regular expression.

```
Student Names:
    Name1
    Name2
    Name3

Parent Names:
    Name1
    Name2
    Name3
```

I am using the following method to match the data and I am not supposed to modify the method. I have to come up with regular expression that works with this method.

```
public void parseName(String patternRegX){

        Pattern patternDomainStatus = Pattern.compile(patternRegX);
        Matcher matcherName = patternName.matcher(inputString);
        List<String> tmp=new ArrayList<String>();

        while (matcherName.find()){
            if (!matcherName.group(2).isEmpty())
                tmp.add(matcherName.group(2));
        }
}
```

I came up with a regular expression that could get me the desired result, but the problem I found was that grouping doesn't work inside square brackets([]).

> private String studentRegX="(Student Names:\n[ +**(\S+)**\n]+\n)";

I am using the following regular expression now, but that is getting me only the last name in each set.

> ```
> private String studentRegX="Student Names:\\n( +(\\S+)\\n)+\\n";
> private String parentRegX="Parent Names:\\n( +(\\S+)\\n)+\\n";
> ```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You're not going to get a collection of names (ala Dot-Net). Any quantified repeat resets (overwrites) any containing group. You could however use the `\G` anchor construct to handle both student/parent names in a single regex. Is that something you'd be interested in?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope you can change the `parseName` method a little bit, because it doesn't compile.  `patternDomainStatus` and `patternName` are probably supposed to refer to the same object:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternRegX);
    Matcher matcherName = pattern.matcher(inputString);
```

Secondly, you need to think about your regex a little differently.

Right now, your regexes are trying to match entire chunks with multiple names in them.  But `matcherName.find()` finds "the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern" (per the javadoc).

So what you want is a regex that matches **a single name**. `matcherName.find()` will loop through each part of your string that matches that regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already familiar with the difference between repeating a capturing group and capturing a repeating group, that's worth reading up on.  One resource for that is http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html, but others would be fine too.

If you already knew about that difference and were trying to capture a repeating group already with what you've written above, then please edit your post to explain what you're trying to do (a letter-by-letter explanation would be ideal, so we see what you understand and what you don't, so we can help you with whatever you're stuck on).

I see what I believe is the solution, but since this is clearly homework, I'm not willing to simply give it to you.  But I'd be happy to help you figure it out.

--- Edit: ---

You're only getting one match because the regex requires "Student Names:" or "Parent Names:" to be in **each** match, so you can only match once.  For your regex to match multiple times in a row (as required by the `while (matcherName.find())`), you need to get the "Student Names:" and "Parent Names:" out of the regex, so the regex can match repeatedly.

It's easy to get **all** of the names (both students and parents), with just a regex that looks for newlines followed by one or more spaces and then text.  The challenge is to differentiate the student names (which come before the "Parent Names:" line) from the parent names (which come after the "Parent Names:" line).  The key concept for differentiating between them is [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which can be positive or negative.  Take a look at them and see if you can figure out how to implement this using lookaheads.

Also, you may find that group #2 isn't the group you really want to use.  It's unfortunate that the group number is hard-coded, but since it is, you can tweak your regex to make groups non-capturing with `(?:stuff)` syntax.  That will let you reduce the number of groups and ensure that the group you actually want is #2.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was useful. But I am yet to come up with a final regX. The problem is that I cannot modify the method. I have to come up with a regX that with capture one name at a time.

Comment: You're right that the link I gave you didn't really lead in the direction you need to go; sorry.  I'll edit my answer with info to hopefully lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Because regex has little to do with algorithmic prowess, here an answer:

- On Windows the line break is unfortunately "\r\n".
- I check that a newline preceded and that there is at least some white space before the name.
- The name may have a space.
- With look-behind I check that "Parent Names" follows.

Then

```
Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=\n)[ \t]+([^\r\n]*)\r?\n(?=.*Parent Names)");
//               ~~~~ '.' also matches newline
//                   ~~~~~~~ look-behind must be newline
//                          ~~~~~~ whitespace (spaces/tabs)
//                                ~~~~~~~~~~ group 1, name
//                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ look-ahead
```

Without say, a bit different algorithm would be more solid and understandable.

To make it group(2) instead of the above group(1), you could introduce extra braces before: `([ \t]+)`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the `\G` anchor all in a single regex.
This opens it up for a little regex algorithmic prowess.
Each match will be either:

- Group 1 is not NULL/empty - New student group, group 3 will contain first student name.
- Group 2 is not NULL/empty - New parent group, group 3 will contain first parent name.
- Group 3 is never NULL/empty - The first/next either student or parent name depending on which
  group 1 or 2 last matched.

In all cases, group 3 will contain a name that has been trimmed and ready to put into an array.

---

```
 # "~(?mi-)(?:(?!\\A)\\G|^(?:(Student)|(Parent))[ ]Names:)\\s*^(?!(?:Student|Parent)[ ]Names:)[^\\S\\r\\n]*(.+?)[^\\S\\r\\n]*$~"

 (?xmi-)                     # Inline 'Expanded, multiline, case insensitive' modifiers
 (?:
      (?! \A )                    # Here, matched before, give Name a first chance
      \G                          # to match again.
   |  
      ^                           # BOL
      (?:
           ( Student )                 # (1), New 'Student' group
        |  ( Parent )                  # (2), New 'Parent' group
      )
      [ ] Names: 
 )
                             # Name section
 \s*                         # Consume all whitespace up until the start of a Name line
 ^                           # BOL 
 (?!
      (?: Student | Parent )      # Names only, Not the start of Student/Parent group here
      [ ] Names:
 )
 [^\S\r\n]*                  # Trim leading whitespace ( can use \h if supported )
 ( .+? )                     # (3), the Name
 [^\S\r\n]*                  # Trim trailing whitespace ( can use \h if supported )
 $                           # EOL
```